# TypeError: document.getElementById(...).files is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function uppp(id){
    var eleme = "uploaded_image"+id;
    alert(id);
  var name = document.getElementById(id).files[0].name;
  var form_data = new FormData();
  var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if(jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) 
  {
   alert("Invalid Image File");
  }
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById(id).files[0]);
  var f = document.getElementById(id).files[0];
  var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;
  if(fsize > 2000000)
  {
   alert("Image File Size is very big");
  }
  else
  {
   form_data.append("file", document.getElementById(id).files[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/wat/admin/category/uppp/"+id,
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){
     $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
    },   
    success:function(data)
    {
        var x = document.getElementById(eleme);
        x.style.color = 'green';
        x.innerHTML= "done";
    }
   });
  }

  }
```

this function function is supposed to get the file name from the input control then post the details to a php file which will upload the name in the database. the function is working "selectively"... that is sometimes it works and sometimes it produces the error above... here is the php file from where the file name is taken... please help

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                            $document_id= $row["document_id"];
                            $document_description = $row["document_description"];

                         $output .= "</tr>";

                         $output .= "<tr> ";

                          $output .= "  <td class='text-center'><p class='nums'>".$count."</p></td>
                            <td>
                                 <input type='text' name='' class='textdd' value= '".$document_description."' disabled>
                            </td>
                            <td word-wrap:break-word'>
                                 <input type='file' name='file' id='$document_id' size='20' required  />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <button name='$document_id' onclick='uppp(this.name)'>Upload</button>
                            </td>
                            <td id='uploaded_image$document_id' color='red'></td>
                            ";

                    $output .= "</tr>";
                    $count++;



               }
                $output .= "<tr> <td> <input type = 'submit' value='Save Documents' class='btn btn-info'> </td> </tr> ";
                $output.= " </tbody> </table>";
                  echo $output;
                }
                else{

                    $output .="<td class= 'noresults'> NO documents Found </td>  </tr> ";
                     $output.= " </tbody> </table></form>";
                      echo $output;
```

Comment: CTRL+f `id='files'` returns nothing....

Comment: Your file input(s) have a dynamic id of `$row["document_id"]`, but your javascript is explicitly looking for the id `'files'`

Comment: thanks .. that was a typing error  on the question i corrected the question now

Answer (score 0):

i realized that i had elements from different tables with the same id on the same page . this was because of creating the ids dynamically from 1 to 100. so when the function is passed an id which belongs to two elements that`s when the error occurred.

i realized that when creating ids dynamically for elements the creation process should be as unique as possible